# why does cursoradapter check mDataValid and if the cursor is null?

Tags: android, overriding, android-cursoradapter

I'm new to android, and I was trying to implement a custom adapter. I was taking a look at the Cursor Adapter source code (to override a few functions) when I saw this:

```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        return mCursor;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

when I went to check what mDataValid was, I saw:

```
void init(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    if ((flags & FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) == FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY) {
        flags |= FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER;
        mAutoRequery = true;
    } else {
        mAutoRequery = false;
    }
    boolean cursorPresent = c != null;
    mCursor = c;
    mDataValid = cursorPresent;
    mContext = context;
    mRowIDColumn = cursorPresent ? c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id") : -1;
    if ((flags & FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) == FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) {
        mChangeObserver = new ChangeObserver();
        mDataSetObserver = new MyDataSetObserver();
    } else {
        mChangeObserver = null;
        mDataSetObserver = null;
    }
    if (cursorPresent) {
        if (mChangeObserver != null) c.registerContentObserver(mChangeObserver);
        if (mDataSetObserver != null) c.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }
}
```

Isn't this redundant? What should I do when overriding the getItem function?

P.S. -> I want to insert an extra custom row in the beginning(not from the cursor)

Comment: `"P.S. -> I want to insert an extra custom row in the beginning(not from the cursor)"`, use `CursorWrapper` then (or `MergeCursor`)

Comment: Thanks! should I edit MoveToPosition only or should I also edit movetofirst and movetolast? Also, can it be done in the way I asked? and is mDataValid redundant or is there some reason both conditions are checked?

Comment: first try `MergeCursor` it is a lot easier than custom `CursorWrapper`

Comment: Actually, MergeCursor Looks a lot easier. thanks!